# Not getting "requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit" errors in Xcode, build succeeds when it should fail

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an Xcode project that doesn't use `self.` inside of a closure where it's needed.

```
class Example {
    func bar() {   
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }

            print(foo) // should be print(self.foo), but not getting an error here
        }
    }
    
    var foo: String {
        "foo"
    }
}
```

Despite this, the build succeeds. I expect the following error to appear:

> Reference to property 'foo' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit

My environment: Swift 5.8.1/Xcode 14.3.1

Comment: Unrelated to the question but the entire `self`-dance is pointless because this kind of GCD closure won't cause a retain cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct if you are using Xcode 14.3 • Swift 5.8 or later. Take a look at Swift evolution's [Allow implicit self for weak self captures, after self is unwrapped](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0365-implicit-self-weak-capture.md).

Comment: Would anyone know if this can be disabled?